# Using ApplicationContextAware in Bean class to initialize prototype scope bean members

Tags: java, spring

I am learning spring and I was just playing around with `ApplicationContextAware` and bean scopes.

I will be attaching the code and then describe what I want to do.

So far, I have created a

**Point class:**

```
public class Point {
private int x;
private int y;

public int getX() {
    return x;
}
public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}
public int getY() {
    return y;
}
public void setY(int y) {
    this.y = y;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "x: "+this.x+",y: "+this.y;
}

}
```

I have created a **Triangle** class which has 3 instances of this **Point** class:

```
public class Triangle implements ApplicationContextAware, BeanNameAware{

private Point pointA;
private Point pointB;
private Point pointC;
private String beanName;
private ApplicationContext context=null;

public Point getPointA() {
    return pointA;
}

public void setPointA(Point pointA) {
    this.pointA = (Point)this.context.getBean("point1");
}

public Point getPointB() {
    return pointB;
}

public void setPointB(Point pointB) {
    this.pointB = (Point)this.context.getBean("point2");
}

public Point getPointC() {
    return pointC;
}

public void setPointC(Point pointC) {
    this.pointC = (Point)this.context.getBean("point3");
}

public void draw() {
    System.out.println("BeanName is: "+this.beanName);
    System.out.println(pointA);
    System.out.println(pointB);
    System.out.println(pointC);
}

@Override
public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext arg0) throws BeansException {
    this.context = arg0;
}

@Override
public void setBeanName(String arg0) {
    this.beanName = arg0;
}
}
```

Below is **spring.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 5.1.1//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-5.1.1.dtd">

<beans>
<bean id="triangle" class="org.java.learning.Triangle" >
    <property name="pointA" ref="point1" />
    <property name="pointB" ref="point2" />
    <property name="pointC" ref="point3" />
</bean>

<bean id="point1" class="org.java.learning.Point" scope="prototype">
    <property name="x" value="0" />
    <property name="y" value="0" />
</bean>

<bean id="point2" class="org.java.learning.Point" scope="prototype">
    <property name="x" value="20" />
    <property name="y" value="20" />
</bean>

<bean id="point3" class="org.java.learning.Point" scope="prototype">
    <property name="x" value="-20" />
    <property name="y" value="20" />
</bean>
```

And this is the **Main class:**

```
public class DrawingApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
        Triangle t = (Triangle) context.getBean("triangle");

        t.draw();
    }
}
```

So, you would have seen that bean scope of three beans, `point1`, `point2` and `point3` is `prototype`, but they are members of `bean triangle`, whose scope by default is `singleton` in `spring.xml`

So, my assumption is, this should not work, unless I can somehow get `ApplicationContext` in my `Triangle` class and set `pointA`, `pointB`, `pointC` respectively like I have done in their setter methods using `ApplicationContext.`

Not sure if this is correct way or not, or how useful is this thing in live applications.

So, if it all above code works, I should get three lines output like:

```
x: 0,y: 0
x: 20,y: 20
x: -20,y: 20
```

But when I run the main method I get following error:

> WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling 
>       refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
>       Error creating bean with name 'triangle' defined in class path resource 
>       [spring.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is 
>       org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested 
>       PropertyAccessExceptions (3) are:
>       PropertyAccessException 1: 
>       org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'pointA' threw 
>       exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
>       PropertyAccessException 2: 
>       org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'pointB' threw 
>       exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
>       PropertyAccessException 3: 
>       org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'pointC' threw 
>       exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
>       Exception in thread "main" 
>       org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean 
>       with name 'triangle' defined in class path resource [spring.xml]: Error 
>       setting property values; nested exception is 
>       org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested 
>       PropertyAccessExceptions (3) are:
>       PropertyAccessException 1: 
>       org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'pointA' threw 
>       exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
>       PropertyAccessException 2: 
>       org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'pointB' threw 
>       exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
>       PropertyAccessException 3: 
>       org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'pointC' threw 
>       exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1685)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1400)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:144)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:85)
>       at org.java.learning.DrawingApp.main(DrawingApp.java:9)
>       Caused by: org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested 
>       PropertyAccessExceptions (3) are:
>       PropertyAccessException 1: 
>       org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'pointA' threw 
>       exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
>       PropertyAccessException 2: 
>       org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'pointB' threw 
>       exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
>       PropertyAccessException 3: 
>       org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'pointC' threw 
>       exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at 
>    org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:122)
>       at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:77)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.app 
>       lyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1681)
>       ... 13 more

I believe I have done something wrong while setting the values of **pointA, pointB and pointC** member variables

Please let me know if any details required from my side, to get rid of this error and achieve what I am trying to do.

Comment: You seem to be using very old materials. At the _very_ least, use the generic form of `getBean`: `getBean(Triangle.class)`.

Comment: Why are you doing this `public void setPointB(Point pointB) {
    this.pointB = (Point)this.context.getBean("point2");
}`. If you are injecting via setter you should have to have "bean-standard" setter

Comment: I was injecting via setter earlier, but then I tried to set values using context object and not using the ones passed in setter method.

Answer (score 1):

Independent to your error you are facing: Let's have a look at your classes setup:

You want your points to be prototype. So each time you request a new Bean by injection Spring gives you a new instance.

And now you inject your prototype beans in your Triangle bean which is by default singleton (which means it is requested and created only once). So the prototype beans (Point) are also requested once to inject them into the singleton Triangle bean.

From now on your prototype beans doesn't act like prototype beans, which means they inherit the singleton scope from your Triangle bean.

But on this setup you're fine, but you should keep that pitfall in mind: Spring creates new instances of prototype beans only if the beans are requested from the container/context.

Comment: So, the reason it doesn't work here is that prototype beans are also injected as singleton beans now ?

Comment: No that doesn't cause an exception

Answer (score 1):

You are getting NPE because context object is null in below and similar methods

```
public void setPointC(Point pointC) {
    this.pointC = (Point)this.context.getBean("point3");
}
```

context Object would be set in ApplicationContextAware beans only when all the beans are initialized and context object is ready.

Your code should look like below

```
public void setPointC(Point pointC) {
        this.pointC = pointC;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Two reasons cause you code throws exception：

- `new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml")` method can't Aware the class context is ready.
- A loop dependency. create `ApplicationContext` need success create all beans,but the `Triangle` need a context.

You can use IOC to solve your problem.